# Error/confusion when using pipe vs function call

Tags: elixir

So far in my attempts to make a pinochle deck I have

```
deck = for rank <- ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K','A',], suit <- ['C','D','H','S'],  blackwhite <- ['B','W'],  do: %{suit: suit, rank: rank, blackwhite: blackwhite}
|> Enum.shuffle
```

However, the shuffle portion seems to shuffle the inner portion of the map rather than the maps themselves.   BUT, when switch out the pipe for

`Enum.shuffle(deck)`

I get the expected results. Wondering the reason for it and if there is a better way as always.

Comment: That's probably because of ambiguity of what the pipe should be applied to. My guess is it's being applied to the `%{suit: suit, rank: rank, blackwhite: blackwhite}` map instead of the entire result of the `for`. You could wrap all of the arguments for `for` in parentheses e.g. `for(rank <- ..., ) |> Enum.shuffle()` and you should get the expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, due to operator precedence. [`|>/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#%7C%3E/2) is an operator and [operators precede](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/operators.html#operator-precedence-and-associativity) macro invocation. Basically, pipe has the same precedence as multiplication operator in the example below, that’s why it’s applied to the map, not to the result of `for/1` invocation.

```elixir
for i <- [1, 2, 3], do: i * 2
```

To achieve the desired functionality, use parentheses.

```elixir
deck =
  (for rank <- [...], suit <- [...],  blackwhite <- [...],
    do: %{suit: suit, rank: rank, blackwhite: blackwhite})
  |> Enum.shuffle
```